# Firestore Rules - allow query of a collection doc if the respective subcollection doc contains a value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So the Firestore Database structure looks like this:

`Collection1/Doc1/Subcollection1/Doc2/Field1`

I am trying to write a Firestore rule so that when I make a query for Doc1 in Collection1, it is only allowed if Field1 contains a specific value.

I wrote the following rule, but I get error when performing the query:

```
match /Collection1/{documents} {
allow read: if request.auth.uid in
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Collection1/Doc1/Subcollection1/Doc2/).data.Field1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a different way to read the subcollection of the collection I am querying, without using `get()` but using `resource['__name__']` something?

**EDIT:**

I add the details below.

The Firestore Database is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCdgI.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuMsk.jpg

The actual Firestore Rule is this:

```
match /Invitations/{documents} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null
      && request.auth.uid in
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Invitations/$(resource.data.eventCode)/Private/$(resource.data.detailsDoc)).data.invitedUidList;
}
```

The query looks like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('Invitations')
  .where('eventCode', isEqualTo: "2kMvcKpFH48V5zR5MPiQ")
  .get()
  .then(...);
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you also share your query code if the following rule doesn't work correctly? Security rules are not filters so make sure your query will pass any rules.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the value of document ID captured by the wildcard in your path. Try the following rule:

```
match /Collection1/{docId} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Collection1/$(docId)/Subcollection1/Doc2/).data.Field1;
}
```

Comment: Doc1 and Doc2 ID values are actually saved in two different fields of Doc1 (let's call them Doc1IDfield and Doc2IDfield).

My actual rule is as follow:
```
allow read: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Collection1/$(resource.data.Doc1IDfield)/Subcollection1/$(resource.data.Doc2IDfield)/).data.Field1;
```

Comment: @Vittorio I think it'll be much more clear if you share screenshots of your documents from Firestore console and then explain. You can update your question with the same. Also please add code of the query that you are running

Comment: I updated the post with more info, if it can help. Thank you!